# Can I return an optional from a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, boost, std, constexpr, boost-optional

- Can I return an `optional` from a `constexpr` function?
- Why?
- If yes, how does it work?

I'm interested in both `boost::optional` and `std::optional`. Do they behave the same?

Comment: with `std::optional` surely you [forgot about the c++1y tag](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/trip-report-iso-c-spring-2013-meeting)?

Comment: @sehe thanks for the edit! What is the difference between `std::optional` and `boost::optional` that allows this? Will it ever be possible in `boost::optional` for c++11 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`boost::optional` cannot be returned by a `constexpr` function. Or at least, the documentation provides no *guarantees* of this.

However, `std::optional`, as defined by the accepted C++14 proposal, *can* be returned by a `constexpr` function. But ***only*** if the type argument of the `optional` is trivially destructible.

This allows the destructor of `std::optional` to be trivial in those cases. At which point, there's no difficulty in destroying the object, so there's nothing stopping `std::optional` from being a literal type.

[The proposal is quite clear on this.](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html#rationale.constexpr) If `T` is trivially destructible, then most of the constructors of `optional` will be `constexpr`, and `optional<T>` will be a literal type. And therefore, it can be created in a `constexpr` function.

Answer (score 6):

Boost.Optional does not support `constexpr`, mainly because it was written before C++11 was released.

The [current proposal for `std::optional`](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html) does support `constexpr`, as long as the value type `T` is trivially destructible.  It [works because](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html#implementability) `constexpr` constructors are allowed for unions (7.1.5p4); the compiler tracks which union member is initialized, ensuring that the undefined behaviour of accessing the value of a disengaged optional is caught at compile time:

```
struct dummy_t {};
template <class T>
union optional_storage {
  static_assert( is_trivially_destructible<T>::value, "" );
  dummy_t dummy_;
  T       value_;
  constexpr optional_storage(): dummy_{} {}  // disengaged
  constexpr optional_storage(T const& v): value_{v} {}  // engaged
  ~optional_storage() = default;
};
```

The value type must be trivially destructible because `constexpr` is only useful with literal types, which must themselves have a trivial destructor.

For example, writing:

```
constexpr optional_storage<int> o{};
constexpr int i = o.value_;
```

gcc gives the error:

```
error: accessing ‘optional_storage<int>::value_’ member instead of initialized 
‘optional_storage<int>::dummy_’ member in constant expression
```